# Eclipse project building error

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am currently working on a java project with Eclipse 3.6.1 and an annoying error pops every time I build the project.
The exact error message is in French:

> **Erreurs de génération.**
>   **Erreurs lors de lexécution du générateur {0} sur le projet {1}'.**
>   **2**

Which I could translate by:

> **Generation errors.**
>   **Errors when running generator(builder I assume) {0} on project {1}'.**
>   **2**

The funny thing is that as long as I dismiss the error message and I recompile it works.

I tried deleting the .metadata which did not work.
I also tried to restart from a fresh workspace with no results.

If anybody could help me it would be wonderful.

Thank you

Comment: Open the **Error Log** view, clear it (using the red X button), then wait for the build error to happen. At that point, inspect the **Error Log** to see if there is anything relevant.

Comment: Thank you for our response. From what I saw on the error log, the error come from calling plugin code __org.eclipse.core.resources__. 
The error is exactly an ArrayOutOfBoundsException in __org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.rpmlint.parser.RpmlintParser.parseRpmlintOutput(RpmlintParser.java:172)__. Quite obscure for me...

Comment: Unzip your Eclipse 3.6.1 or [one of these Eclipse 3.6.1 packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-361/heliossr1) to another directory and see if that unzip works better.

Comment: I will try that and keep you posted(certainly tommorow as the internet connection is so awesome that it needs the end of times to download the package). Thanks!

Comment: Just to check, I assume you are actually using "org.eclipse.linuxtools", if not you can consider uninstalling those plug-ins.

Comment: @JonahGraham That is kind of the problem I think, but as I am not root in my work environnement, I do not have the hand of the Eclipse install.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc this package is apparently not available in 64bit, I tried with the 32bit version but it does not launch on my VM. I will try to unpack a newer version in 64bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this the wrong way, i.e. by using a n[ewer version of Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars1), Mars1.
I will ask our IT guy if this is something he encountered with other coworkers.

Thanks for your responses!